# Setting up a Twilio gateway with django-two-factor-auth

Tags: django, two-factor-authentication

I can't find any documentation telling me how to set up a Twilio SMS gateway, other than to install the twilio client, and add some urls (http://django-two-factor-auth.readthedocs.org/en/1.2.2/configuration.html#twilio-gateway).

I know I need to plug in the Twilio api keys somewhere, where do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the [documentation of version 1.3.0](http://django-two-factor-auth.readthedocs.org/en/1.3.0/configuration.html#twilio-gateway) which includes elaborated setup instructions. More specifically, you need to set the following constants in your django project's settings:

- `TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID`: Should be set to your account’s SID.
- `TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN`: Should be set to your account’s authorization token.
- `TWILIO_CALLER_ID`: Should be set to a verified phone number. Twilio differentiates between numbers verified for making phone calls and sending text messages.